# Geth solo mining with trex possible? - General questions / Job handling on different mining tools

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, full-node, solo-mining

i'm pretty new to this topic but like to learn how things are working. I got some general questions to the different miner-settings available.
First of all i know about pool-mining and how to set it up for different pools and i also know about the fact that solo mining is not worth but as i said i like the technical things and try to set different things up to make it work.
I'am using geth. Got it full synced and added the "--mine" command to enable the ability to mine. Complete command :

```
geth.exe --http --miner.etherbase 0x42f1DE45fe91d741C968C4C976E19d3e2224EC16 --ethash.cachedir "K:\Blockchain_Ether\Blockchain\geth\ethash/cache/" --ethash.dagdir "K:\Blockchain_Ether\Blockchain\geth\ethash/dag/" --datadir "K:\Blockchain_Ether\Blockchain" --keystore "K:\Blockchain_Ether\Blockchain\keystore" --syncmode "full" --mine
```

This works fine i guess because when i attach to the node i get a "sync=false"-state  which occured when the currentblock hitted the highest block.
Complete Command:

```
geth.exe attach ipc:\\.\pipe\geth.ipc
```

When succesfull attached:

```
eth.syncing
```

If i gonna proof my Accounts with the following command i got my Adress which is totaly fine:

```
eth.accounts
```

Proofed my balance with the following command which returns 0 which is also fine:

```
eth.getBalance("0x42f1DE45fe91d741C968C4C976E19d3e2224EC16")
```

I would say that the node is running good this way.

**Here comes the part i'am unsure about.**

There are a lot of incomming mining work-jobs as you can see on the following screenshot:
[image: Geth synced node]

I started a mining-tool called "etherminer" with the following command:

```
ethminer.exe -U -P http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

This workes good as i think. I mean the mining-tool stays synced with all the jobs incomming from geth. I proofed it by comparing the sealhash. Following Screenshot of the working etherminer (from another timestamp so hash-values are not matching)
[image: etherminer running]

I was thinking about using the t-rex miner but i'am not sure about the "correct" command. The command i tryed looked like it's working as well but it get's waaaaaaay less jobs then the etherminer.
I started the t-rex miner with the following command:

```
"K:\MiningTools\t-rex-0.24.8-win\t-rex.exe" -a ethash -o stratum+http://127.0.0.1:8545 -u 0x42f1DE45fe91d741C968C4C976E19d3e2224EC16 --mt 3 --pl 80 --fan t:60 --lock-cclock 0 --cclock 100 --mclock 100
```

Following screenshots showes the running t-rex miner with less jobs:
[image: t-rex running]

**Now my questions... :)**

1. Geth is sending a lot of jobs. Like a lot of jobs between each complete block. Etherminer is recieving all these jobs and starting to mine on every single job? Is there a reward for every single job? Compared to t-rex miner it looks like this tool only get the "full-block-job" which results into less incomming jobs. Is this just a visual thing that t-rex is not showing the micro-things happening between the lines ot is it not working this way? How is the reward system on that different methods?
2. I can start t-rex with different algorythms. In my case i used ***-a ethash***, does ***-a etchash*** would work as well and i just can choose on which algorythm i got more hashrate?
3. When i start the miner in geth with the following command on the attached console: ***miner.start(2)*** It should start the CPU-Mining-Function with 2 Threads. (I got an i7 8600k with 6 Threads), but my CPU is instantly raising to 100%. Why is this the case? And when i try to stop the miner with the command ***miner.stop*** it dont work. The CPU stays on 100%. This only can be solved by terminating the complete synced geth node and restarting it. On bot commands i get the return value NULL which should be fine. But something is not working properly i guess.
4. Does one of my setups should work? So based on my informations, would it be possible to find a block theoretically (low chance i know)? Port 30303 is  still closed it seemed to be not neccesary - hopefully i'm right? :)

Hopefully there are some people to help me:) I just like technical things and just want to make it work, understanding things. Any help even to understand the whole things more and more would be awesome!

Take care - stay healty !

Answer (score 0):

### How basically startum mining works

1. Consider mining on geth over getwork (the rpc enabled one).
2. Let's say a job has possible hash range of numbers from `1 to 100`.
3. Let the correct share be the hash of number `52`.
4. So when using ethminer, it starts to search from 1 to 100 for the hash (Not exactly in this manner, but consider as an example)
5. So it took 10s to find `52` was the number for the hash

   Coming to the protocol which trex uses (stratum)

- Startum protocol is the most used one's in mining pools
  This will help the pool to divide the above range of `1 to 100` for different miners

1. So let A, B, C and D are the miners connected to the pool
2. Pool divides the range to search for each miner
3. Let the range

   - 1-25 for A
   - 26-50 for B
   - 51-75 for C
   - 76-100 for D
4. For the above job, the correct number is within the range given to C
5. So if it took 10s for ethmine to reach the number `52`, per hashing time could be ~0.01s
6. So here C would find the hash within ~0.03s

- Which is way faster than the ethminer alone
- And the block reward will be distributed to A, B C, and D with respect to their hashrate

`That's about the T-Rex`
So the solution is T-Rex should be able to communicate to your geth node via a stratum interface like this

`T-Rex` <--> `Stratum` <--> `Geth Node`

### Which algorithm to choose

- Ethereum blockchain uses `ethash` or `Daggerhashimoto` as the algorithm to calculate the hash of the blocks
- So you cannot use a different algorithm to submit a hash for the block.That would be invalid

  - ETC will take Etchash
  - ETH will take Ethash
  - RVN will take Kawpow
  - Bitcoin will take SHA256 and so on..

<sub>Will be thankful and welcome for corrections</sub>